# SEO de HTML vs ASPX

Tags: html, seo, semântica, aspx

Eu tenho um site estático que foi montado há muito tempo atrás que são arquivos `.Aspx`. (Ele só é em `ASPX` porque eu utilizo no form de contato).

Minha pergunta é simples: "Vale a pena eu converter meu site `.Aspx` para `.Html?`".

Eu quero que o *SEO* dele fique melhor para ser reconhecido pelos robos do google, o `.Aspx` é **pior ou igual** ao `.Html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente não, o SEO leva em consideração se a URL é bem escrita/intuitiva e descritiva, se é `.html` ou `.aspx` ou `.foobar` (é possível customizar) não vai influenciar.

Creio que no máximo alguns site "maquiam" a url tipo `.php` ou `.aspx` ou `.jsp` para `.html` (com *url_rewrite*) para que as pessoas não saibam qual tecnologia o site usa.

Uma url "melhor" (mais intuitiva) seria algo como:

```
http://site/artigo/seo-de-html-vs-aspx.aspx
```

O que não difere muito disto:

```
http://site/artigo/seo-de-html-vs-aspx.html
```

Ainda sim não por questão de SEO mas sim para facilitar a vida do usuário, algo assim seria o ideal:

```
http://site/artigo/seo-de-html-vs-aspx
```

Não dá para afirmar o comportamento dos BOTs, muito menos afirmar que *url_rewrite* vai ter rank melhor no Google e afins, urls assim são apenas um dos muitos pontos necessários para subir no rank, por experiencia própria lhe digo que URLs bem escritas são sim melhores, mas não fazem você ficar na frente de outros sites, pois existem outros fatores com peso muito maior.

Leve em consideração que o BOT do google vive mudando, não dá pra afirmar nada com precisão.

Comment: Achei tua resposta mais acertiva à minha pergunta. Obrigado cara, bem esclarecedor ! =)

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Jackson,

Não sou um expert em SEO mas pelo que compreendo da ferramenta o google utiliza os links para realizar a indexação, assim se seu endereço é um endereço válido na internet não importa se é aspx, html, php e ou outros.
Para entender melhor dê uma olhada neste link http://monge.com.br/blog-detalhe-seo-consultoria-web-sites/como-o-google-exibe-os-resultados-de-pesquisas/16 pois o cara deu uma resumida no funcionamento.

Para uma melhor indexação e aparecer nas primeiras posições em uma consulta existem várias empresas especializadas em SEO que podem te assegurar um melhor ranking. Você também pode estudar as técnicas e tentar aplicar você mesmo, algumas dicas podem ser encontradas no site http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/o-que-e-seo/

Sobre converter o seu site vai depender muito da sua necessidade, caso a atual tecnologia não atenda sua demanda vale a pena, do contrário, sugiro apenas você realizar uma alteração para tornar as suas views responsivas, ou seja, adaptando-se ao dispositivo de acesso. Isto torna o ambiente mais agradável ao usuário que acessar de um smartphone e ou tablet.

Espero ter ajudado ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Boas referencias e informações :)

Comment: Imagina Jackson, o objetivo é sempre nos ajudarmos! :)